# DISTINCT ON (col) col_alias – alias not working

Tags: postgresql, distinct-on

I am trying to run this command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (_id) test FROM creator_map.infos;
```

which is giving me the error:

> ERROR:  column "test" does not exist

but according to the following tutorial, the `test` should be an alias

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT ON
 (column_1) column_1_alias,
 column_2
FROM
 tbl_name
ORDER BY
 column_1,
 column_2;
```

[Source](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/).

How do I get the distinct to become an alias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't give `on (...)` an alias because it's not expression that "returns" a name. It's like trying to give an `IN` condition an alias `where a in (1,2,3) as foo`

If in doubt, read [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). It does not mention an alias there.

You can only define an alias for an expression in the actual select list, and the `(...)` is not part of the select list, but part of the `distinct on` expression.

I think it's just a matter of bad wording on that tutorial page, and should read:

```
select distinct on (column1) 
          column1 as column_1_alias,
          column2
from ....
```

Comment: yes, that tutorial threw me for a loop because they straight up say "column alias" as if its an alias for the ON statement. Super confusing, I hope they fix that.  To select everything i just did `ON(someColumn) *` which returns all columns